# Best date format for timestamps in a MongoDB document?

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
I am not sure what date format that is the most "flexible" for the timestamp of
each document in the database.

Currently I am using: *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss*

Is it better (for mongodb searching and internationalization) to use another format?

My question is just this, what is the best format for a timestamp in a MongoDB document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the years, I have been forced to a very strong personal commitment to always storing date/time as the 10-digit Linux/Unix timestamp, which gives the current (add: local) time as seconds since the Epoch. Just a few moments ago, the time was 1329126719. To me, this is the most flexible format possible. When it comes time to display a date/time, it's simple to convert the 10-digit timestamp to any string you care to show.

**Edit:** Perhaps a better choice for me would be milliseconds from the Epoch, since that seems to be increasingly favored as the art evolves.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps epoc timestamp is the best? Is it possible to do a MongoDB find query between two dates in Epoc format?

Comment: I'm not a MongoDB user, so I'm only *somewhat* sure that the find query would not be between two *dates*, but between two 10-digit *integer values* representing two Epoch time points. MongoDB wouldn't know these are dates; only you would know that. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Jonathan Clark -- Here's a posting that explains it and also makes my answer totally wrong! http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/ I apologize to you because it seems I've make some assumptions about MongoDB that were completely erroneous.

Comment: I would like to add that just the timestamp is not always enough however. In many cases you want to to store the timezone as well. http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html explains a few of the reasons.

Comment: So setting created_at to a unix timestamp will prevent me from searching between two dates?

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB has a built-in datetime type which interacts with the datetime types in your application's language (in PHP they become [MongoDate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) instances). MongoDB datetimes are always stored in UTC, and are internally stored as milliseconds since the UNIX epoch. This means that they are compact (they are always 8 bytes, as opposed to string formats which are longer depending on how much precision you choose to store). Additionally, the MongoDB tools all "understand" datetime objects -- you can manipulate them easily from javascript in a Map-Reduce, or using [the new aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework+-+Expression+Reference#AggregationFramework-ExpressionReference-DateOperators).

Comment: This is the better answer for the MongoDB specific question.